# React Router v4 recursive go back

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a component which renders another

```
class Items extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
  }

  render() {
      return () {
         <div>
            <div><Link to="/items/new">Go To Form</div>
            <div>
               <Switch>
                  <Route path="/items/new" component={New} />
                  <Route path="/items/:id" component={Item} />
               </Switch>
            </div>
         </div>
      }
  }
```

If I call `goBack()` from the `New` component it renders New component again but I can't understand why.

```
 class New extends React.Component {
    // here is costructor

    componentDidMount() {
       this.props.history.goBack();
    }         

    // render
 }
```

So when I click on Go To Form it moves me to New component, then it's mounted and `goBack` is called and I'm redirected to the `Items`. It's OK, but after this `New` is mounted again and I'm redirected to route which was before `/items`. I tried to do it with `go` and there is infinite loop in this case. Also, when I try to do `push` instead of `go` and `goBack` it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I've found out the solution. I use `ConnectedRouter` from [react-router-redux](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux) package. I've changed it back to `BrowserRouter` and it works without any problem. It's similar to a bug with the previous component.